# Change Google App Script Trigger From OnOpen to Time Based

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using below script and the trigger of the script in on open i.e when I open the sheet the script runs and give the desired result. The script is working perfect as desired.

Now I want to change the trigger form opening the sheet to run automatically every 48 hours at mid night 1 AM.

Any support on above will be appreciated.

```
function installedOnOpen(e) {
const editors = ["abc@abc.com", "xyz@xyz.com"];
const sheetNames = ["Sheet1"];
const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => 
sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
if (sheets.length == 0)
return;

sheets.forEach(s => {
const p = s.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
if (p.length > 0) {
  p.forEach(pp => pp.remove());
}


// Gets all the values from col1 to col16 up to the last row 
var range = s.getRange(1, 1, s.getLastRow(), 16).getValues();
var lastRow = range.length - 1;

/*
the for loop below checks the rows from the bottom up 
and will stop once it encounters a non-empty row.
This mimics the behavior of the getLastRow() method 
but restricts it to columns 1 - 16
*/

for (lastRow; lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {
  if (range[lastRow].join('').length > 0) break;
}

if (lastRow != 0) {
  const startRow = 6;
  const numRows = lastRow - 4;
  const newProtect = s.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 16).protect();
  newProtect.removeEditors(newProtect.getEditors());
  newProtect.addEditors(editors); // Added
  if (newProtect.canDomainEdit()) newProtect.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
 });
 }
```

Comment: You will not be able to open up a user interface without a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it can be done. Let's say your existing code is inside myFunction.

```
function myFunction() {
  ...
}
```

Now, you just need to run the below function once to set the trigger for myFunction to run every 2 days (48 hours) at 1 AM.

```
function setTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
           .timeBased()
           .everyDays(2)
           .atHour(1)
           .create();
}
```

Comment: @ ab.it.gcp Thank you for the solution. I tried it and the script ran at the time set in the trigger but it failed due to some error. As you have provided solution to the problem and the solution is running proper but there must be some other error and hence I am closing this question and posting a new question for the error.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked! I've responded with an answer on the other question as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78087273/google-appscript-time-based-trigger-is-showing-error/78088427#78088427