# Google AppScript Time Based Trigger Is Showing Error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using two App Script (1) To lock the Spread sheet (2) Set the time based trigger to run the 1st script every day at specific time.

The time based script runs automatically but gives and error "ReferenceError: e is not defined at myFunction(Code:4:18)"

Below are both the scripts:
(1) Script for auto lock of Google Sheet :

```
function myFunction() {
const editors = ["abc@abc.com", "xyz@xyz.com"];
const sheetNames = ["Sheet1"];
const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => 
sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
if (sheets.length == 0)
return;

sheets.forEach(s => {
const p = s.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
if (p.length > 0) {
  p.forEach(pp => pp.remove());
}


// Gets all the values from col1 to col16 up to the last row 
var range = s.getRange(1, 1, s.getLastRow(), 16).getValues();
var lastRow = range.length - 1;

/*
the for loop below checks the rows from the bottom up 
and will stop once it encounters a non-empty row.
This mimics the behavior of the getLastRow() method 
but restricts it to columns 1 - 16
*/

for (lastRow; lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {
  if (range[lastRow].join('').length > 0) break;
}

if (lastRow != 0) {
  const startRow = 6;
  const numRows = lastRow - 4;
  const newProtect = s.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 16).protect();
  newProtect.removeEditors(newProtect.getEditors());
  newProtect.addEditors(editors); // Added
  if (newProtect.canDomainEdit()) newProtect.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
 });
 }
```

(2) Script to set time based trigger

```
function setTrigger() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
       .timeBased()
       .everyDays(1)
       .atHour(2)
       .nearMinute(01)
       .create();
     }
```

Any solution on above will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *ReferenceError: e is not defined at myFunction(Code:4:18)*

To fix that error, you should add the missing parameter `e` to the function declaration, like this:

```js
function myFunction(e) {
```

That will not make the function work, though, because time-driven trigger [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) lack the `source` field. To get the active spreadsheet in a time-driven trigger, use `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`, like this:

```js
function myFunction(e) { // e unused
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const editors = ['abc@abc.com', 'xyz@xyz.com'];
  const sheetNames = ['Sheet1'];
  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName => {
    const s = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    s.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).forEach(p => p.remove());
    const rangeToProtect = s.getRange('A6:P');
    const values = rangeToProtect.getDisplayValues();
    let numRows = values.length - 1;
    while (numRows && !values[numRows].join('')) numRows--;
    if (!numRows) return;
    const newProtect = rangeToProtect.offset(0, 0, numRows).protect();
    newProtect.removeEditors().addEditors(editors);
    if (newProtect.canDomainEdit()) newProtect.setDomainEdit(false);
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that this worked? Since you are using a time based trigger, my understanding is that e.source would return undefined and the function will fail.

Comment: @essem This solution would solve the "e is not defined error.." but you would face a different error. Hence it doesn't fit as the accepted answer as the functionality is not achieved. Request you to check again and accept the other answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the "e" in your code anymore as you are using a time based trigger instead of a simple (onOpen, onEdit..etc) trigger.

Change the following statement in your code

```
const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => 
sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
```

to below

```
const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().filter(s => 
sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: yes but the event object does have useful information in it and it provides that information at a much lower cost in time than using external functions to obtain identical information.

Comment: In the code posted in question, e is not being used for retrieving any other info apart from getting the spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes but it provides the spreadsheet without requiring a function being run to get it.  Or saying another way that function has already be run why run it again in the trigger handler.

Comment: It won't provide the spreadsheet. e.source will return undefined as the function is triggered through a time based trigger and not a simple trigger